# Trying to marry up 2 sets of dates

Tags: sql

I am looking for some assistance

Is there anyway in SQL to say that between 2 timestamps a value holds for calculations.
I have a table which holds values similar to this:

```
1/1/2007 07:00 1058; 
2/1/2007 12:00 1058;
24/1/2007 07:00 1055.5;
```

I need to be able to say that between the 2 dates the value holds so that I can perform calculations against another table with hourly values

Comment: Are you trying to use `SELECT sum(value_field) (FROM table) GROUP BY <date_field>`?

Comment: Is the goal that there should be a "virtual" value for all days between the 2nd and the 24th?

Comment: I am trying to work perform a calculation using the above data as a 'constant' for a time period.  So for a value with a timestamp of 1/1/7 12:00 I would use the value of 1/1/2007 07:00 and for one at 24/1/7 09:00 I would use the value at 24/1/2007 07:00

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds like you're looking to see if a value sits between 2 dates.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable m
   INNER JOIN RangeTable r ON m.MyDate BETWEEN r.StartDate and r.EndDate
```

Comment: Hi Jason - thanks for this - would it interpolate the values between the dates?

Comment: Be aware that the limits on `BETWEEN` are inclusive so `A between B and C` is the same as `A >= B and A <= C` which can cause problems if A exactly matches one of your given lookup values.